# How to draw dynamically on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, render, erb

**Goal**: I want to show a preview of a banner in a web app.

**Stage**:
Suppose I have a Banner model with these fields:

- text
- vertical_align
- horizontal_align

User should have a square to preview text and if user select top and left, this text must be rendered at top-left corner in the square.

I'm using Rails 3.0.9.

**Problem**:
I don't have idea how to implement this or if there is some "plugin" to make it easier.
Should I use some canvas widget? I don't know.

Please help me!
Thank you very much.

P.D. If you need more info please feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that [rmagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) and [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) will give you what you need. There are many examples available online including [this blog post](http://www.gra2.com/article.php/using-rmagick-imagemagick-rails).

Good luck! :)